# Third person equivalent of "yours" and "mine"

Tags: pronouns, possessives, singular-they

What is the third person equivalent of *yours* or *mine*? For example,

> It's not your book; you should take yours.
>
> It's not my book; I should take mine.
>
> It's not his book; he should take X.

Comment: "[T]o the English personal pronouns *I, you, he, she, it, we, they*, there correspond the respective possessive determiners *my, your, his, her, its, our* and *their*, and the respective possessive pronouns *mine, yours, his, hers, its* (rare), *ours* and *theirs*." — [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive#From_pronouns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right. "Yours" in the third person is "his". Examples of this could be:

> Your right hand shook like a leaf.
>   His right hand shook like a leaf.
>   I only took what was rightfully mine.
>   He only took what was rightfully his.

Comment: but also third persons: hers, its (singular); theirs (plural)